# The count of an array seem inconsistent if there's only one element in an array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm creating an array below with the same content:

```
$disk = @("C:","C:","C:")
```

When I removed all the duplicates and show how many count in an array it is not showing anything but there's an element.

```
$disk = $disk | select -uniq

PS D:\powershell> write-output $disk
C:

PS D:\powershell> $disk.count
PS D:\powershell>
```

It looks like it is no longer an array but rather a string as shown below:

```
PS D:\powershell> write-output $disk[0]
C
PS D:\powershell> write-output $disk[1]
:
```

What I need is to remove all the duplicates and even if there's only one element left, it should remain as an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct that `$disk` becomes a string:

```
PS > $disk = @("C:","C:","C:") 
PS > $disk = $disk | select -uniq 
PS > $disk.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                      
True     True     String                                   System.Object                                 

PS > $disk.Length
2
PS >
```

To fix this problem, tell PowerShell to treat the result as an array by enclosing it in `@(...)`:

```
PS > $disk = @("C:","C:","C:")    
PS > $disk = @($disk | select -uniq)   
PS > $disk.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                      
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                      
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array                                  

PS > $disk
C:  
PS > $disk.Length
1
PS >
```

Comment: It's a shortcut and you should stick to iCodez' answer, but in PowerShell 3 and later a count property is added if one does not exist.  See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847751.aspx (ctrl+f 'count').